# Dijkstra algorithm. Getting to unvisited Node that is "Cut off" from the current node by some other node

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

In Dijkstra algorithm, what if one of the unvisited nodes in a graph is "cut off" from the current visited node by some other visited node. So say I'm in node A which is linked to node B, and node B is linked to unvisited node C. However node B has already been visited so I can't visit it again. How do I get to C?

Answer (score 0):

a value for C will already be computed in the distance array when you were visiting node B. Simply when you're visiting node C it won't update this existing value as the computation `dist(src, A) + inf` is greater than `dist(src, B) + dist(B, C)` or also because your implementation has another way to describe the impossibility of a path. `dist(src, B) + dist(B, C)` would be the effective result of the computation of the dp while visiting B as the shortest path from src to B would have been computed